# Angular 4: Redirecting user to last visited page in previous session on login

Tags: javascript, angular, spring

I have a task of redirecting an user to the last visited page after s/he logs in. Now I clearly have to store the router Url of the last visited page in my backend. My question is how can I do that so that I do not have to make a lot of backend calls? I am using Angular 4 + Spring boot. Please help me with suggestions and ideas.

Comment: a subscription to Router.events filter by Navigation.End in main.app and store in localStore?

Comment: @Eliseo But the last session of the user may be 5 days prior. In that case how would storing in localStore help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the last navigation status in local storage, which you can refer to later. For an example, you add something like following to your app component.

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        const lastVisitedUrl: string = localStorage.getItem('last_visited_url');
        localStorage.removeItem('last_visited_url');
        if (lastVisitedUrl) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(lastVisitedUrl);
        }
        router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                localStorage.setItem('last_visited_url', event.url);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to redirect a user to login page if not logged in, when they try to navigate to a particular url. My requirement is that I need automatically redirect the user to the last page s/he had visited in the last session. The last session may be 5 days before.

Answer (score 2):

storing the last route in local storage seems like a good fit here, since this shouldn't be sensitive data (unless your routes contain sensitive data). this avoids having to make network requests on each route change, or on initial load.

There are two downsides to this approach

1. local storage doesn't persist across multiple devices.
2. a user can always manually clear out what's in their local storage. but these would be for users that want to spend the time doing this.

For the sake of completeness, I'll also mention that you could use a cookie to store this data. Though, I would recommend local storage over cookie for this type data. keeping in mind that cookies suffer from the same downside as listed in point 2 above.

if the requirements give you leeway where the above aren't concerns, I suggest local storage. However, if the requirement for maintaining the last visited page is critical to the application, there is no avoiding the extra HTTP requests as you are persisting state at this point. In this scenario, I would suggest explaining the trade off to the stakeholders to see if these use cases are acceptable.

Good luck

Comment: Is there a common way of achieving this? Like every time the user routes to a new URL, this common code takes that url and calls a service. If yes, where should I be writing that code?

Comment: @LahiruChandima provides a great example above of how you can subscribe to router changers. Since you are looking to capture every route change, you will need to make sure this code is high up in your your component structure. i.e. placing it in the app component works. Simply add your http within the "if (event instaceof Navigationend) condition and that should get you there.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think that storing the URL each time it changes is the most effective solution because identifying when the user stops using the application is more complicated and has a lot of use cases to consider.